# Getting all data from the super class (this =)

Tags: java, oop

I'm not sure what would be good OO design in the following case.

First of all I know you cannot use:

```
 this = anObject;
```

But my sitiuation is as follows. I have a superclass (Film) with over 20 data fields. A subclass (ComedyFilm) extends the superclass and has just 3 additional data fields.

This is the code I would like to place in my subclass:

```
public ComedyFilm(GenericFilm parent, FilmRating rating) {
        this = parent;

}
```

So that when creating a new instance of ComedyFilm, it would be something like:

```
Film myFilm = new Film(.... long constructor);
ComedyFilm myComedyFilm = new ComedyFilm(myFilm, FilmRating.EIGHTEEN);
```

Is there an easy way to do this without getting/setting every single variable in the constructor? Without doing

```
   this.filmName = parent.filmname;
   this.directors = parent.directors;
   //etc...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just create another constructor that takes the film data and the rating and internally calls that long super constructor?

Comment: Why do you create a Film and then a ComedyFilm? why not just a ComedyFilm that would have a long constructor or just getters and setters?

Comment: what about a super(filmName, directors ...)?

Comment: Film is not abstract but has many classes extending it, not only ComedyFilm. It has also for example DramaFilm, etc.. That also answers your question, talnicolas.

Comment: I'm reading many films from a file. They can be comedy films, drama films etc.. but they are all films. Passing the superclass to the subclass would save me time if there's an easy, shorthand way to do it, but apparently there isn't any such thing as this =. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived class should defer to the base class constructor for copying base class fields. What this means is that the very first line of your ComedyFilm constructor will be `super(someArgumentsForTheBaseClass)` followed by whatever you need to do to initialize your derived class.

Comment: _Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor_. (from [Using the Keyword super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html))

Answer (score 2):

You should have.

```
public class ComedyFilm extends Film {
    public ComedyFilm(GenericFilm parent, FilmRating rating, FilmName filmName, Directors directors) {
       super(FilmName filmName, Directors directors);
       //bla
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with some factory method which would create `ComedyFilm` from `Film`:

```
Film myFilm = new Film(...);
ComedyFilm comedy = ComedyFactory.createComedyFilm(myFilm, FilmRating.EIGHTEEN);

public class ComedyFactory {
    public static ComedyFilm createComedyFilm(Film parent, FilmRating rating) {
        ComedyFilm comedy = new ComedyFilm(parent);
        comedy.setRating(rating);
        return comedy;
    }
}
```

But you'll still need to create constructor in `ComedyFilm` that would copy every property from prototype (in this case, from `Film`). That's how prototypes work, don't they?